# cannot use hasOne relationship to place restriction

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, has-one

i have hasone relationship between models "member" and "loan". i throws "trying to get property of non object error

i have tried on hasMany and it all works but it has to be in hasOne, there is no restriction to stop multiple loan being issued to a member.

**Member.php**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Member extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['name','address','phone']; 

    public function loan()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Loan::class,'member_id','id');
    }

    public  function savings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Saving::class,'member_id','id');
    }
}
```

**Loan.php**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Loan extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'amount',
        'interest',
        'status',
        'member_id',
        'loan_type_id',
        'interest_type_id',
        'loan_payment_type_id'
    ];

    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Member::class,'member_id','id');
    }
}
```

**member.blade.php**

```html
<td>{{$member->name}}</td>
<td>{{$member->address}}</td>
<td>{{$member->phone}}</td>
<td>
    <a href="{{route('deletemember').'/'.$member->id }}">Delete</a>
    <a href="{{route('editmember').'/'.$member->id }}">Edit</a>
</td>
<td>
    {{$member->loan->amount}}
</td>
```

Comment: is that $member null

Comment: So you're trying to use `hasOne` as a way to prevent a `Member` from having more that one loan?

Comment: yes indeed. it have made foreign key member_id unique in the loan table. i just need exception handling on that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe all of your member don't have a loan. that's why error shown, Try to check before echo,

```
  <td>
   @if($member->loan)  // add this line code
     {{ $member->loan->amount }}
   @endif  // add this line code
  </td>
```

Comment: yes it doesn't throw error if ll members have loan but once a new member is added, it gives the error.i'll try implementing

Comment: see my answer add if condition before print loan amount.

Comment: You are most welcome. If this answer worked accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
{{$member->loan['amount']}}
```

Comment: your answer would be better to be a comment under the question especially since it has no explanations whatsoever for what happens when you 'try'

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.